# Is there a better way of handling static columns than grouping in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a lot of denormalized data which I need to do some calculations on. There's about 28 columns, 1 of which is an ID column, 5 of which I need to sum, and the rest of which I just need to report. So 22 of these columns are always the same for a single ID. Currently I'm grouping on the 23 columns and then summing the 5. This seems to me like it probably has undue overhead. Is there a better way to handle it?

Here's the script after the initial load:

```
grouped = GROUP inputData BY
(SITE_ID_COL,
 META_ID_COL,
 ITEM_ID_COL,
 SELLER_ID_COL,
 CATEGORY1_COL,
 CATEGORY2_COL,
 TOTAL_WATCH_COL,
 ITEM_TITLE_COL,
 AUCT_TYPE_COL,
 CURRENCY_COL,
 ITEM_PRICE_COL,
 SHIPPING_TYPE_COL,
 SHIPPING_FEE_COL,
 START_DATE_COL,
 TOTAL_QTY_COL,
 QTY_AVAIL_COL,
 STATUS_ID_COL,
 AUCT_DURATION_COL,
 END_DATE_COL,
 LOGIN_ATOL_COL,
 LOGIN_LATEST_COL);

filtered = FOREACH grouped GENERATE
  flatten(group),
  SUM(inputData.IMPRESSION_COL),
  SUM(inputData.CLICK_COL),
  SUM(inputData.BIDCOUNT_COL),
  SUM(inputData.QTY_SOLD_COL),
  SUM(inputData.CK_TRANS_COL),
  SUM(inputData.GMV_COL);

STORE filtered INTO 'output/';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, whether or not this is faster really depends on your data set and cluster, but you can try Regenerating your data with just the id and 5 summed columns, and then joining back onto the 22 "reported" columns after. Something like:

```
smallerData = FOREACH inputData GENERATE ITEM_ID_COL, IMPRESSION_COL, ...;

reportingData = FOREACH inputData GENERATE ITEM_ID_COL, [OTHER 22 REPORTING COLS];
reportingData1 = DISTINCT reportingData;

grouped = GROUP smallerData BY ITEM_ID_COL;

filtered = FOREACH grouped GENERATE
  flatten(group) AS id,
  SUM(inputData.IMPRESSION_COL),
  SUM(inputData.CLICK_COL),
  SUM(inputData.BIDCOUNT_COL),
  SUM(inputData.QTY_SOLD_COL),
  SUM(inputData.CK_TRANS_COL),
  SUM(inputData.GMV_COL);

joined = JOIN filtered BY id, reportingData1 BY ITEM_ID_COL;

STORE joined INTO 'output/';
```

If your grouped set has way fewer rows than your input set, this will probably make things faster. It'll also go a long way towards preventing you from running into java heap space issues, which pig is known to have when you wind up with very wide rows (i.e. after groups).

If that's not the case, your original way will probably be faster because joins are definitely not something you want to use in Pig unless you have to.

Answer (score 2):

one other way you can deal with this problem is ,
taking group variables from file so that your code look clean and
in case if you want to change the group variables you can easily change.

> Step 1.

declare variables like below in a file groupparams.txt

```
groupvariables = col1,col2,col3,col4 .....etc
```

> step 2

use the above variable in pig script file like below (say pigscript.pig)

```
B = group a by $groupvariable
```

> step 3

run script like below

```
pig -paramfile=groupparams.txt pigscript.pig
```